# Jenkins : Defunct process are generated after JNLP connection with a slave and it gets very slow

Tags: java, jenkins, solaris, jnlp, defunct

I’m facing an issue while connecting a slave (solaris sparc 8) with Jenkins ver. 1.532.2

This slave is connected via the option “Launch slave via execution of command on the Master”.

Connection is established with:

- Connecting to the slave via FTP
- Executing java command: **/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java** -jar slave.jar **-jnlpUrl** file:///...

This way, the connection is successful.

However, the slave gets extremely slow and a lot of defunct process are generated (parent of these is java process PPID). It’s a real problem because no jobs can run on this slave.

I can’t find the reason why there is zombie generation .... can you please help on this? Any idea is welcomed.

Thanks you.

Best regards.